# Correct grammar / style for segments that share the same (lengthy) prepositional object

Tags: commas, prepositional-phrases, dashes, prepositional-objects

I'm having trouble with a sentence that uses two (or more) prepositional phrases, which share the same prepositional object. For example, I would like to turn these two statements:

> A main theme in this thesis is the proper use of X in Y.
>   Another main theme in this thesis is the safety profile of Y.

into:

> The two main themes in this thesis are the proper use of X in, and the safety profile of, Y.

The above format is based on advice found online [HERE](http://www.editoraustralia.com/styleguide_commas.html) (relevant section reproduced below):

> #### Segments that share the same prepositional object
>
> Use commas to separate off sentence segments that share the same prepositional object.
>   E.g.   *‘She flew over, and he sailed under, the Wordsmith Bridge.’*
>
> <sub>Choosing Your Mark, p. 25 (15)
>
>   Style Manual p. 82 (6.60)</sub>

However, while I find that this approach works with their sentence, I find that (subjectively) my example above is much less aesthetically pleasing.

At the risk of sounding like I'm asking for opinions rather than confirming / exploring suitable grammar options, is this the right / only way to do this, and if not what are appropriate alternatives?

For instance, are m-dashes / 'interruption' n-dashes allowed / preferred / recommended? E.g.

> The two main themes in this thesis are the proper use of X in --- and the safety profile of --- Y.
>   The two main themes in this thesis are the proper use of X in--, and the safety profile of, Y.

---

<sub>PS: Note that while the 'comma' and 'n-dash' methods would allow for more than two segments, the 'm-dash' method does not, but this is not a problem for me in this particular instance. But please share your thoughts either way.

***Edit: ->*** PS2: In response to Edwin's excellent comments, I'm reluctant to duplicate Y in that sentence because in my case it corresponds to a very lengthy object which would result in a very bad sentence. (Title edited appropriately to reflect this).</sub>

Comment: Keep it simple: just remove *in* so __The two main themes in this thesis are the proper use of X and the safety profile of Y.__ Your other solutions are understood but not great.

Comment: The parallelism is insufficient to make the first alternative idiomatic. I'd not reduce further than _The two main themes in this thesis are the proper use of X in Y, and the safety profile of Y._  Some days, I might even stick with the original two-sentence version.

Comment: The constructions you're concerned with are RNR (Right Node Raising) constructions, if you want to do a web search for more info.

Comment: I agree with Edwin's reduction. "Main theme" sounds rather trite, especially when repeated. "This thesis examines the proper use of X in Y, as well as the safety profile of Y."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth (and Mark), unfortunately the reason I don't want to repeat Y in this case is because it is rather long in itself, and would make the sentence very cumbersome and repetitive. (Y is something like long, e.g. say, "autonomous decision-making in the context of medical procedures")

Comment: @GregLee thank you, that was very useful to know! I have found an old paper called [Right Node Raising and Preposition Stranding](http://www.jstor.org/stable/4178482) (alas, paywalled). This seems to use the comma syntax consistently, so I'm happy to consider this as evidence that this is indeed the grammatically correct way to express this construct in writing. If you'd like to post an answer along those lines I'd be happy to accept it. Many thanks also to the other answers suggesting alternatives.

Comment: i can only suggest bulleted points. I'd consider that deleting one of the Ys would reduce cumbersomeness(!) only minimally, while decreasing readability. // Please note that Greg Lee has given answers (eg at ' "Neither…nor” with “to” and “by” ') addressing RNR here before, so requesting general information is essentially encouraging duplication.  Your example is different in being very heavy.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth it's not really appropriate for my context (though I'm making this a bigger issue than it is, I was more curious about the right way to write this on paper more than anything). But this sentence is literally a oneliner preamble before my introduction chapter outlining its content. Splitting it and saying "another main theme" sounds a bit weird in that context. I suppose given the second preposition is "of", I can get away with converting it to a posessive i.e. "[...] X in Y, and their Z". I'll see if that looks better. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth apologies I just spotted the 'duplication' comment, maybe I missed it when I replied (or perhaps that was part of the edit? I'm sure I would have addressed such a concern in a reply!). I searched the site thoroughly before asking and couldn't find anything relating to prepositional objects *specifically*. I could add the term RNR in the title I suppose but I feel that would be editing the question title to include the answer, which is probably not the intent. You are right about 'heaviness' being important though, I will edit the title accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why no-one wanted to attempt an answer outside the comment section, but I suppose I should answer this question myself based on the discussion in the comments for the benefit of future googlers.

As per Greg's comment, the constructions concerned are RNR (Right Node Raising) constructions. More importantly, they are RNR constructs applied to prepositional objects.

I have found an old paper called Right Node Raising and Preposition Stranding (alas, paywalled), which seems to use the comma syntax consistently, so I would consider this as evidence that this is indeed the grammatically correct way to express this construct in writing, particularly in the context where the prepositional objects involved are lenghty in nature.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Answers hidden in comments are a big problem.